# Use tkinter scrollbar with canvas and pack

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm using widgets packed in a canvas. I'm using the pack geometry manager since it is quite flexible and adapt automatically the window to the size of the widgets (the size and number of widgets per row are not constant). But sometimes I have too many widgets and they don't all enter in the window. 
So I've tried to use a scrollbar.

However if I keep the pack method, the scrollbar is useless. For example, here is my code :

```
import tkinter as tk

class Interface:    
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.bind('<Control-w>', lambda e: root.destroy())

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root)

        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.root, command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y')
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill='both', expand=True)

        self.fill()

        bbox = self.canvas.bbox('all')
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)


    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))



    def fill(self):
        ordered_list = [['element in row {}, column {}.'.format(i, j) for j in range(i % 10 + 1)] for i in range(100)]

        for elements in ordered_list:
            frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
            for e in elements:

                label = tk.Label(frame, text=e)
                label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            self.label = frame
            frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Interface(root, main, machines)
    root.mainloop()
```

When I encapsulate my widgets in a frame and I draw this frame in the canvas, the scrollbar work. But I loose the automatic size of the window corresponding to the size of my widgets, and when I extend the window, the frame stick in the corner, not in the middle as with the pack method.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Interface:    
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.bind('<Control-w>', lambda e: root.destroy())

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root)

        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.root, command=self.canvas.yview)

+       self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y')
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill='both', expand=True)

        self.fill()

+       self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame)
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox('all')
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)


    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def fill(self):
        ordered_list = [['element in row {}, column {}.'.format(i, j) for j in range(i % 10 + 1)] for i in range(100)]

        for elements in ordered_list:
+            frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
            for e in elements:

                label = tk.Label(frame, text=e)
                label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            self.label = frame
            frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Interface(root, main, machines)
    root.mainloop()
```

So, is there a way to keep the pack method in a canvas with a scrollbar, or to have the flexibility of pack with the frame drawn in the canvas (automatic size of the window, widgets which stays in the center) ?

Comment: What is difference between first code and second. It would be easier if you specified the difference exactly, rather than have people going line by line comparing them. Also what are `main` and `machines`?

Comment: I added a `+` before the modified lines. `main` and `machines` are only part of my real code I forgot to remove.